# What is the most simple/cheapest way to create visible Facebook posts programmatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook App that posts on a Facebook page of mine with a page access token. Everything is working fine except I am the only one able to see the posts even though the post privacy/visibity is set to everybody.

I know the App must be toggled to live but in 2019 it's a whole lot of bureaucracy: approvals, website, privacy policy page and even a contract. I sort of have to prove that my App is legit for all users but all I want is for it to publicly post on a one of my Facebook pages. There has to be a workaround.

What is the most simple/cheapest way to create visible Facebook posts programmatically?

Comment: There is no workaround, you MUST put the App live. Although, you should not need to go through the review process if you are the only one using the App, and if it´s just to post on your own page.

Comment: @luschn I think not all permissions are available any more in live mode, if not reviewed - not even to app roles. `manage_pages` currently seems available without, but `publish_pages` isn’t. (Going by what the permission dialog in Graph API Explorer shows.)

Comment: oh, did not know that, thanx. well, in that case: app review it is ;)